# Finding the last Vector of a right angled triangle - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, geometry

For Context: I'm 90% of the way through making a wall running system in Unity, and I need help finding 2 Vector3's that I can use for a check and for adding velocity to the player to get them to move in the correct direction.

More specifically, I'm getting two Vector3's to the right and left of a contact point with a wall, then getting the distance between the right point and the players previous position, and the distance between the left point and the players previous position. Whichever point is further away from the player, is the direction we are travelling, and if you take that point and - the contact point from it and normalize that, the function returns the Vector3 to use to add velocity to the player.

Currently I'm using this function to do this for me (where hit is the contact point between the player and the wall):

```
Vector3 CalculateWallRunDirection(Vector3 hit, Transform wall)
{

    Vector3 rightPos = hit + wall.forward;
    Vector3 leftPos = hit + (wall.forward * -1);

    float rightDis = Vector3.Distance(rightPos, prevPlayerPos);
    float leftDis = Vector3.Distance(leftPos, prevPlayerPos);

    if (rightDis < leftDis)
    {
        return Vector3.Normalize(leftPos - hit);
    }
    else
    {
        return Vector3.Normalize(rightPos - hit);
    }

}
```

This works well when it works... but the problem is, because I'm using the Transform.forward of the wall to determine where these points are, if you try to wall run on the front or back face of an object, it will throw to into the wall instead of along it and the player will become stuck.

TL;DR: I need another way to determine two Vector3's instead of using transform.forward + original Vector3. From a top-down view, the problem could be displayed as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfywO.png). A is the player, B is the contact point with the wall. Find C and D:

Please explain your answer, I'm not too great at math.

Comment: What is A and B in the context of the reference? Also it would be easier to use the direction of the player to determine the "direction you're traveling" as you cannot wall-run backwards. You could also just get the player's velocity from its rigidbody and normalize that to get the direction the player is moving

Comment: A is the players position, B is the contact point with the wall. I actually do want the player to be able to wall run backwards, as weird as that sounds. Think similar to Lucio from overwatch, if you've played that. One way or another though, I still need the vectors to add to the player's velocity

Comment: So am I right to assume you want a new vector that is parallel to the contact surface in the direction the player was traveling?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

You were essentially trying to recreate [Vector3.ProjectOnPlane()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html). You probably want to use that instead.

eg

```
Vector3 A = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(B, C);
// A is the new velocity vector parallel to the wall
// B is the old velocity of the player at the point of impact
// C is the normal of the plane of impact
```

You can easily find C in the `OnCollisionEnter` event, simply get the contact point's normal.

Note B doesn't need to be normalized, but if it is, A will be a normalized Vector3 as well.

Comment: Hold on, So should I be replacing my whole function with that?

Comment: Nevermind that question. Thank you so much, it's working properly now.